# Why does a Flask app create two process?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

As far as I understood Flask should create a thread and a second thread to run on it, but what I see is there are always two processes, not threads, running. 
Even for the simplest app.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, flash, session, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

app.run(host="192.168.21.73", port=5000, debug=True)
```

You can see two process running:

```
ps -x
5026 ttyO0    S+     0:01 /usr/bin/python ./test_flask.py
5031 ttyO0    Sl+    0:45 /usr/bin/python ./test_flask.py
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's because you're running the dev server with the reloader.  The reloader monitors the filesystem for changes and starts the real app in a different process, so there are two total processes.

You can disable the reloader by settting `debug=False` or `use_reloader=False` when calling `run`.