# Python POST requests executed twice on Flask App

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have Flask App deployed with nginx and gunicorn.

while requesting post request from my flask app, it is executed twice.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['POST'])
def search():
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:6800/schedule.json', data='{"project":"rental", "spider":"airbnb"}')
        return json.dumps(r.json())
```

Here 2 different spider jobs are created.

Answer (score 1):

It is because that the reloader spawns two processes when you run it. 
You can disable it by settting `debug=False` or `use_reloader=False` when you are running it.

Check out the answers of the questions:

- [Why does a Flask app create two process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585033/why-does-a-flask-app-create-two-process)
- [Why does running the Flask dev server run itself twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504149/why-does-running-the-flask-dev-server-run-itself-twice)

Comment: i am in production environment not in dev

Comment: So your app is a single process, but creating two spider processes?

Comment: Could you please share controller code receiving the post. The code above is just posting.

Comment: what is the max_proc setting for the scrapyd. Seems as if the daemon starts seperate threads of the same spider. The documentation from the scrapyd "Scrapyd also runs multiple processes in parallel, allocating them in a fixed number of slots given by the max_proc and max_proc_per_cpu options, starting as many processes as possible to handle the load."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135528/discussion-between-ganesh-pandey-and-ozgur-eroglu).