# Is it possible to run flask in a single process? (to work around apparent issue with ipdb & Docker ttys)

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a flask app which I am running like this:

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

When I look at the process list I see this:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 23:48 pts/0        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c flask run --host=0.0.0.0
root         6     1  1 23:48 pts/0        00:00:01 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0
root         8     6  3 23:48 pts/0        00:00:02 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Three processes.

If I run using `--without-threads` I also the same three processes:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 00:28 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --without-threads
root         6     1  2 00:28 pts/0    00:00:02 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --without-threads
root         8     6  4 00:28 pts/0    00:00:04 /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --without-threads
```

Is there a way to somehow run flask as a single process?

#### Motivation

The flask app in question is running inside a docker container.  I would like to be able to set breakpoints using `ipdb`.

I have observed that if I set this in my docker-compose file:

```
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

and run, instead of a flask app, a simple single-process python app...

```
$ docker exec -it bug_demo_bug_demo_1 bash
root@98245482089b:/opt/bug_demo/bug_demo# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 00:41 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c python app.py
root         7     1 20 00:41 pts/0    00:00:00 python app.py
```

... and attach to the container while the app is at a breakpoint, I am able to drop into `ibpd` and use it normally – arrow keys and tab completion work properly.

But when I try do the same with the flask app (attach to the container while the app is waiting in a breakpoint), things do not work correctly.

Either I disable `tty: true` in `docker-compose.yml`, and can use use `ipdb` but without arrow keys and tab completion, OR I leave `tty: true` in place, but then cannot really use `ipdb` at all, b/c it appears the `tty` is attached to all three flask processes, causing everything other than single character commands to get garbled.  (Although I can see with this setup that arrow keys and tab completion work.)

All of this leads me to believe that if I can find a way to run my flask app as a single process, I will be able to attach to the docker container and use `ipdb` as desired.

Is there some way to do this?

#### Update: problem manifests during startup, not during request handling

Upon further examination, I see that this problem only manifests during "startup" code.  ex: if the breakpoint is inside the `create_app` function.

If the breakpoint is inside a request handler method, or code called from a request handler, everything works as expected.

Using `exec` reduces the process count from three to two (the root process gets replaced by the first worker), but the problem still manifest for breakpoints inside `create_app`.

Running flask with `--no-reload` makes the second worker go away, so process count can then be forced to one or two, by then not using or using `exec`.   Running with `--no-reload` is not ideal for my use case, but it *does* make the problem go away, even for breakpoints in `create_app`.

For my purposes, I can live with the limitation of `ipdb` only playing nice with the terminal inside request handlers -- I don't expect a great need to run the debugger from startup code.  (But I will still accept an answer & happily award the bounty, if anyone can explain exactly what is happening in the startup-code breakpoint case, and why the problem does not manifest in the request-handler breakpoint case.)

Based on the `--no-reload` finding, it does feel like the underlying flakiness is somehow related to the TTY being "shared" by the request handling process and the code-reloading process.

#### Flask & Docker Version Info

```
ipdb> flask.__version__
'1.0.3'
```

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

```
$ docker info
Containers: 22
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 19
Images: 362
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9754871865f7fe2f4e74d43e2fc7ccd237edcbce
runc version: 09c8266bf2fcf9519a651b04ae54c967b9ab86ec
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.125-linuxkit
Operating System: Docker for Mac
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.855GiB
Name: linuxkit-025000000001
ID: ZAK2:V2VU:IZFF:6MQQ:IFJB:2ZKY:VHA5:CSO3:VXQQ:UK6C:O3I7:S3ZU
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 59
 Goroutines: 89
 System Time: 2019-07-28T14:00:38.3184372Z
 EventsListeners: 2
HTTP Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3128
HTTPS Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3129
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

Comment: Are you running your Flask app in debug mode?

Comment: Makato: yes.  does that matter?

Comment: This might be worth a read: [Why does a Flask app create two process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28585033/2745495)

Comment: @billc, please add the output of `docker version` and `docker info` and `docker-compose --version` to your question. Also what flask version and which OS? I tested by creating a simple app on Mac and Ubuntu and i was not able to reproduce the issue. Also will suggest to use `exec flask run --host=0.0.0.0` in your Dockerfile and see if it helps fix the issue

Comment: Version info added.   The `--no-reload` mode, described in the question & dup question linked by Gino does make the problem go away.  Tarun's report of not being able to repro led me to do more testing – the problem actually seems to manifest only during app startup, and not during request handling.

Comment: Under the hood, Flask apps run the [`run_simple()` function](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L876-L892) from the [`werkzeug.serving`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/serving.py) module (see [flask.app](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/app.py#L981-L984) source). Can you try calling `werkzeug.serving.run_simple()` directly?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? did you try something like `docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-2" myapp:latest` ?

Comment: Your objective is just debug your code, or there is another reason for u do that?

Comment: Lucas Araújo -- Yeah, my goal was just to ensure that this project was packaged in a way that would always let me (and other folks on the team) always set and interact with breakpoints in a trouble-free way, as development unfolded.  As per the "Update: ..." section, we basically have that in place (except for startup-time case). But as expected, there has never been much need for folks to monkey much with that code.  Most of our dev time is spent in request-time code, where we have found breakpoint to work fine when accessed via `docker attach`.

Comment: Jose Angel Sanchez -- I did play around with commands like that, but iirc, they didn't solve the problem for startup-time breakpoints.  My "solution" has been to just live with the problem, since I mostly don't need startup-time breakpoints, and have had no trouble getting good behavior from request-time breakpoints, under `docker attach`.

Comment: Flask uses werkzeug server underneath; https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/serving/. For all available options and explanations please refer the above documentation

Answer (score 3):

To make flask run in single processer use the below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=False, processes=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried the "--no-debugger" arguments?
If you have DEBUG environment variable flask create a debugger process.

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --without-threads --no-debugger
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the flask application works on a single synchronous process.

That can only handle one request at a time.

If you want to deal with any parallel requests should wait until they can be handled then use this:

```
app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, threaded=True)
```