# Systemd launches duplicate python processes

Tags: python, flask, systemd

I am using systemd to start a python flask app on raspberry pi zero(Raspbian buster).

Every time I start a service, it launches two python processes instead of one. **Why does this happen?**

[image]

The first process is the parent of the second process.

[image]

Here is my service definition in /etc/systemd/system/website.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Website
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/dev
ExecStart=python /home/pi/dev/app.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the flask app in /home/pi/dev/app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the result of `ps -ef | grep python` when you stop the systemd servic?

Comment: After I stop the service, both processes get killed so `ps -ef | grep python` returns nothing.

Comment: Check this wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, Flask's dev server is running with the reloader so it's launching two processes. If I add `use_reloader=False` when starting the Flask app, it will only start one process.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

More info here: [Why does a Flask app create two process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585033/why-does-a-flask-app-create-two-process)